# Python comparison if statement not working

Tags: python, if-statement, operators

I am just messing around with Python trying to do a simple guessing program. The code inside my if statement never runs, and I can't figure out why. I've tried printing both variables at the end, and even when they're the same, the comparison never resolves to true. I've also tried just setting y as 2 and guessing 2 as the input, and it still doesn't work.

```
import random

x = input("Guess a number 1 or 2: ")

y = random.randint(1,2)

if x==y:  
    print("yes")
```

Comment: `x = int(input(...))`.

Comment: You are comparing a string with an integer.

Comment: Plz check the type of x and y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `x` is a string and `y` is an `int`:

```py
x = input("Try a number ")  # I chose 4 here

x
'4'

x == 4
False

int(x) == 4
True
```

`input` will always return a string, which you can convert to `int` using the `int()` literal function to convert that string into the required value

Comment: Thanks everyone. I’m new to the idea of not having to declare a variable type and I guess casting is needed sometimes to help.

Comment: When in doubt, you can use `type(x)` to see what type `x` is